# Angular JS Forms submit not sending ID

Tags: angularjs, forms, form-submit

I am trying to send the course `id` to the controller in a form button, but it does not seem to work. The controller logs the `vm.add.year` correctly but `vm.add.course` gets `undefined`. Why?

index.html:

```
    <form method="post" ng-submit="vm.addCourseToYear()">
        <table class="table">

            <tr ng-repeat="course in vm.courses | filter:search">
                <td>{{course.courseName}}</td>

                <td><select id="addCourse" name="addCourse" class="form-control"  ng-model="vm.add.year" required>
                    <option value="year1"> Year1 </option>
                </select></td>

                <td><input style="display:none" ng-value="course._id" ng-model="vm.add.course">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="{{course._id}}">Add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </form>
```

index.controller.js

```
function addCourseToYear(){
    console.log(vm.add.course);
    console.log(vm.add.year);
};
```

Comment: Where you set value for `course._id`?

Comment: I get it from the database, the course._id have the right id if i try printing it beside the button like this: {{course._id}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following to fix this:

Add ng-click directive to button:

```
<button type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        ng-click="vm.addCourseToYear(vm.add)"
        id="{{course._id}}">Add</button>
```

Remove the form action leaving just form:

```
<form>
```

Change the function to take a parameter:

```
function addCourseToYear(newItem){
    console.log(newItem.course);
    console.log(newItem.year);
};
```

Change this to initialize vm.add.course as course._id:

```
<td>
    <input style="display:none" ng-init="vm.add.course = course._id" ng-model="vm.add.course">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="{{course._id}}">Add</button>
</td>
```

This follows the patterns found on Angular's site: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Okey, tried this now but still the same problem, the newItem.year prints the right value but the newItem.course is still undefined for some reason @brianslattery

Comment: OK @sacan, I missed one piece. Try the last change I just seeded for initializing the ID.

Comment: Yes, that worked! :D Thank you so much, this have been drivning me crazy @brianslattery

Answer (score 0):

try changing the code to this:

`<form method="post" ng-submit="vm.addCourseToYear(vm.add.course._id)">`

hope this solves your issue .. :)

Answer (score 0):

`display:none` removes the object from the from, 
change it to `visibility: hidden;position:absolute`

```
<input style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;" ng-value="course._id" ng-model="vm.add.course">
```